# Targeting elements except $(this).children(element)

Tags: jquery, exception, this, children

Here is the code, which i am typing about

http://codepen.io/Jacgues/pen/AXakkg

As you can see, I've used to methods to achieve proper functionality of the menu.

The problem is whenever you click Cart position, it doesn't show up.
Seems like it is not targeted correctly, so all elements of this kind are `hide()` but no this particular one, which i would like to set as an exception.

In case of clicking Account or Help, the toggle() doesn't work.

My goal is to achieve toggling the child of the clicked element and hiding all other elements of this kind, except this particular one, certainly.

Could you please assist me?

Comment: You should have posted the relevant code here at SO.

Comment: Ok... I answered correctly, I think. But at the second read of your question, I have to ask about the "exception" you want to achieve. Maybe those "inverted lines" were intended after all... What do you want to do exactly ? Keep the cart dropdown opened ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply "inverted" two lines.
You have to hide BEFORE toggeling...

Like you did elsewhere! ;)

See [your CodePen forked](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EyLBYG).

```
$('.cart').click(function() {
  $dropdown.not(this).hide();
  $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').toggle();

});
```

By the way.... `.not(this)` is ALWAYS `true`.
Since `this` is `$(".cart")`, none of its children element fits.

`$dropdown.hide();` is enought for what you want to do.

You can remove `.not(this)` everywhere.
;)